# Unable to download township game on Lumia 640 XL LTE

Tags: store, app-update

I am unable to download township game & few other games on 640 Xl LTE. Tried changing wifi, setting date time manually, syncing microsoft account but no use. It shows pending or stops midway.

Comment: Do you get an error code at all?

Comment: Do *any* apps work?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to reset your phone. Don't forget to back up your important files.

Comment: Any other way? I found someone else had posted same observation regarding this phone & he had done everything includng reset.

Comment: Reset is needed to make your phone ready for This app. There is probably a software issue on your phone. To delete this issue, you need to reset it.

Comment: Resetting isn't the answer for this.

Comment: You do realise that's the only option?

Comment: And why is that? Why shouldn't there be another good and proper option?

Comment: I may have overstated it by saying it isn't the answer. This probably would work, but it's overkill if there's another way.

Comment: Your phone is wrong configured. And it'll probably be the only option to get these things right. It's a well known bug on WP8.1